Regarding vanishing of a triangle diagram
Furry's theorem ($C$ symmetry) is very important in calculations in QCD, Electroweak theory. Primarily it says everything about QED (three photon triangle diagram), but can be extended to QCD, and ($Z$ sector of electroweak ?), or theories with $C$ invariance. Let us consider the following diagrams

These do cancel each other, as long as there is photon at the right side. I have explicitly checked it. But when I have $Z$ at the right side, things nearly cancel each other, but there are some terms leaving behind. The treatment of $\gamma^5$ have been done in Larin scheme, but this general result should be scheme independent. The reason I expect it to be cancelled out because I have never seen a paper where two gluons fuse to ONE $Z$ boson.
My confusion is why they might not cancel? Are there axial anomaly come into the picture?

Z breaks parity and charge conjugation, no?

you are right. I thought it as $Z$ couples differently with left and right handed quarks. But why nobody has calculated $g+g\to Z$ so far?

Maybe the effective coupling given in the PDG is small
